# Google GeoCharts Colors Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, google-visualization

I have tried multiple things to apply but none of them seem to work to change my charts. I am uploading the array through a file and everything seems to work, even changing the defaultColor, but colorAxis does not seem to work. Could you guys(and girls) help me I would be grateful. Thanks

```
/* CSV handling - START */

var processedData = [];

var continent = $('select[name="continents"] option:selected').val();

$.get('example.csv', function(data) {

    processedData = $.csv.toArrays(data);

}, 'text');


/* CSV handling - END */    

/* Google Charts */



google.charts.load('current', {
    'packages':['geochart'],
    // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.
    // See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load-settings
    'mapsApiKey': //doesn't matter
  });
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawRegionsMap);

  function drawRegionsMap() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(processedData, false);

    var options = {
        sizeAxis: { minValue: 0, maxValue: 100 },
        colorAxis: {colors: ['#e7711c', '#4374e0']},
        region: continent,
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        backgroundColor: 'none'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }

/* Google Charts - End */
```

Comment: please share a sample of the data used to draw the chart -- for _regions_ mode, `colorAxis` needs the second column in the data to be numeric -- see the [data format definition](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#regions-mode-format)...

Comment: `Country,Popularity
    HR,300.00
    RU,100.00
    FR,200.00
    BR,2000.00
    DZ,222.00
    US,333.00
    DE,555.00
    DD,999.00
    SZ,2313.00
    AU,2222.00
    BM,400.00
    CA,322.00`
Here is the sample code. Sorry for the late reply. Spaces represent new line as the comments won't accept new line.

Comment: I've sorted it out. The problem was that csv parser took the numbers as a string. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer To Google Developer reference

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#important

var options = {
          region: '002', // Africa
          colorAxis: {colors: ['#00853f', 'black', '#e31b23']},
          backgroundColor: '#81d4fa',
          datalessRegionColor: '#f8bbd0',
          defaultColor: '#f5f5f5',
        };

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#coloring-your-chart

var options = {
        region: 'IT',
        displayMode: 'markers',
        colorAxis: {colors: ['green', 'blue']}
      };

```
  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
```

Comment: I've tried them all. Like exactly copied and pasted it and everything works except the colorAxis and few visual effects.

Answer (score 0):

using the data from the comment, the chart colors seem to work

recommend removing the options for `sizeAxis`
the values in the data table range from `100` to `2313` (not `0` to `100`),
the chart will handle by default

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var processedData = [
      ['Country','Popularity'],
      ['HR',300.00],
      ['RU',100.00],
      ['FR',200.00],
      ['BR',2000.00],
      ['DZ',222.00],
      ['US',333.00],
      ['DE',555.00],
      ['DD',999.00],
      ['SZ',2313.00],
      ['AU',2222.00],
      ['BM',400.00],
      ['CA',322.00]
    ];

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(processedData);
    var sizeRange = data.getColumnRange(1);
    var options = {
      colorAxis: {colors: ['#e7711c', '#4374e0']},
      //region: continent,
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      backgroundColor: 'none'
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

  },
  packages: ['geochart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```